# Выравнивание текста по ширине

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как перенести текст на следующую строку после определённого количества символов, но так что бы слова не обрезались, а переносились целиком?
Добавляю текст на фото, текст берётся из словаря и может иметь разный размер, Фото 256х342.
Я новичок в python. искал способ решения в интернете, но ни чего подходящего не нашёл.

```
im = Image.open('D:/01_PYTHON/icn/test.jpg')
fnt = ImageFont.truetype('os.ttf', size=32)
draw_text = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw_text.text((35, 70), fact['погода'], font=fnt, fill=('#1C0606'))
im1.save('new_test.jpg')
```

Comment: Где ваши попытки именно разбить строку? :)  Есть несколько вариантов. Можно разбить строку на список через `.split()` и потом собирать обратно, пока размер будет не больше искомого, а потом делать перенос строки. Либо смотреть n-й символ в строке и идти назад по строке пока не найдём пробел и в этом месте делать перенос строки.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, **CrazyElf**, за подсказку. Сделал так:

```
s = 'Разделить строку на список подстрок по разделителю.' #пример
s =s[::-1]
x = s.find(' ',-30,-1)
x =-x
s=s[::-1]
s=s[0:x-1] +'\n' +s[x:-1]
print(s)

Разделить строку на список
подстрок по разделителю
```